# How to deploy complex application in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

Let's say I have classic application with

- Web
- Backend
- DB

If I understand correctly I will create deployment for each of them. What if I want to deploy all in one step? How should I group the deployments. I have read something about labels and services, I'm totally not sure which concept is the right one. There are two ports necessary to face outside(http and debug). Just for clarity skipping any DB initializations and readiness probes.

How can I deploy everything at once?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

Answer (score 4):

You need multiple Kubernetes objects for this and there is multiple ways to solve this.

**Web** - it depends what this is. Is it just **static** JavaScript files? In that case, it is easiest to deploy it with a CDN solution, on any cloud provider, an on-prem solution or possible using a Kubernetes based product like e.g. [KubeCDN](https://github.com/ilhaan/kubeCDN).

**Backend** - When using Kubernetes, we design a backend to be **stateless** following the [Twelve Factor](https://12factor.net/) principles. This kind of application is deployed on Kubernetes using a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) that will rollout one or more instances of your application, possible elastically scaled depending on load. In front of all your instances, you need a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and you want to expose this service with a loadbalancer/proxy using an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

**DB** - this is a **stateful** application, if deployed on Kubernetes, this kind of application is deployed as a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and you also need to think about how you handle the storage with this, it may possibly be handled with Kubernetes [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

As you see, many Kubernetes objects is needed for this setup. If you use plain declarative Kubernetes yaml files, you can have them in a directory e.g `my-application/` and deploy all files with a single command:

```
kubectl apply -f my-application/
```

However, there is more alternatives to this, e.g. using [Helm](https://helm.sh/)

Comment: Maybe I have wrong mindset for kubernetes. How will I handle updates? For development it actually does not matter I will kill it and start again. For other env I understand for yours directory approach or Helm I will have some files / charts per version. I found that helm has some concept of `helm upgrade`. But still I will need Chart per "layer". So in kubernetes it is only way to update "multilayer" application deployment/chart after deployment/chart?

Comment: @Zveratko "update" may be many different things. Usually, you only change a single field in one of those files. E.g. the `image` field of `Deployment` if you want a newer version of the application binary. Then you do `kubectl apply -f my-application/` again and a _rolling deployment_ will update your app without downtime. Or the same procedure if you want to change a config-variable.

Comment: In regular environment install means binary, update skripts and changelog. In cloud/kubernetes I don't understand what exactly makes install package anymore. The app images are clear, I can even understand somehow the deployment files. What about the update scripts. The whole DB idea seems not to fit in the cloud(as many states). The thing is I'm more interested in in-house clouds then any ready made public ones(where they can utilize DB services)

Comment: @Zveratko usually you save the `my-application/*.yaml` files in **git** and what an _updated script_ did in the old days, is now done by editing the yaml files, before commit. Or describe better what you mean by _update scripts_. I also with with Kubernetes on-prem (aka in-house cloud)

Comment: I mean DB update scripts(Flyway, Liquibase etc.). I am really strugling to fit DBs into the picture. Seems like they usually spin up some Flyway server and update the database running in different container. But I need to google a little bit more to find out how do rolling updates go along  with DBs being also updated.

Answer (score 2):

Use helm. You create one helm chart for each of your applications and you can also link them with dependencies ([requirements](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/)). You can then easily deploy them as one application.

Comment: There is also kustomize that is emerging inspired by Helm. It's done by the Kubernetes team and maybe it worth to have a look ...